# combine many json files into one

Tags: php, json

I am trying to combine all json files into one.However  i always receive an empty json file . Here is code ;

```
function mergejson() 
{
    $events = array();
    // open each jsonfile in this directory
    foreach(glob("*.json") as $filename) {  
        // get the contents of the the current file
        $data[] =json_decode($filename, true);
        $events= array_merge($events,$data);
    }
    $file_name ='merge.json';
    $events =json_encode($events,true);
    file_put_contents($file_name,$events);       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [json_decode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) takes a string as first argument, not a filename!

So you have to load the file content, try using `file_get_contents`

Comment: please forgive my lack of knowledge , i am beginner , could you  suggest any code  as a solution .

Comment: Just replace `json_decode($filename, true);` with `json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);` and it should work!